# How to check file in URL exists without using try catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am coding a program to check if a URL is valid in internet. I searched in web, almost all the ways to check the existence of URL are using `try catch`. But I don't want to use `try catch` to check the URL, I just want to use a property or method or any other way to check the existence of URL. 
How can I do it?
I am using Visual studio 2008

Comment: For which reason do you want to avoid a Try Catch block?

Comment: Is your checking for validation of the URL? why not using regex?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Good coding practices say that you should try and validate all possible known errors without lumping everything into a try/catch block and letting it do all your validation.  Checking if a file exists outside of a try/catch is a good practice.

Answer (score 7):

Mate,

Your question is a bit confusing... Are you trying to check whether a file exists in the file system? Or you are trying to check whether a website/page exists somewhere in the internet?

If your trying to check for a file in a file system use....

System.IO.File.Exists

if you are trying to check whether a web page exists in the internet or not. Well, there's no way you can do this safely because you are forced to make an http request and then check for the response back from the server, the response will be an HTTP Code and unfortunately the .NET Framework wrappers of HttpRequest/HttpResponse will throw an exception for http error codes such as 500, 404, 403, 401, etc

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this also depend on whether you are trying to validate a URL exists only for GET or if you are also support GET and POST, or any combination of the HTTP Methods. I will assume you are just using GET.

Are you able to use open source code? A quick search found this library http://www.codescales.com/ that looks like it does not throw exceptions.

For completeness, if you were able to use .NET 4.5 the new `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` does not throw exceptions on non 2xx responses.

Although exceptions are a costly action, I would not be concerned about it unless you are doing many hundreds or thousands of requests per second. The cost of doing this tens of times per seconds should be an insignificant performance hit.